# Flex to wrap with fixed size

Tags: css, flexbox

The title doesn't describe my problem but did'nt find a better one.
So, I have one div containing 3 divs, I wan't two columns with div A in the first one and div B and C in the second, on large screens and one only column on small screens. I could use @media but I think flex can do it without.

This is what I tried:

```
<div id="container">

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

</div>

#container
{
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  max-width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;  
}
#container > div
{
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  margin:2px;
  flex-grow:1;
  min-width:200px;
  height:10px;
}
#container > div:first-of-type
{
  height:300px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j2brc3t3/)

I fixed the height to force the content to go to 2 columns but then it never goes to onel colum.

Comment: why not using bootstrap?

Comment: Because I need it to work even inside a div with a specific width for example...

Answer (score 2):

**Just remove the last css element:**

https://jsfiddle.net/j2brc3t3/1/

**Live example:**

```css
#container
{
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  max-width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;  
}
#container > div
{
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  margin:2px;
  flex-grow:1;
  min-width:200px;
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But then it never goes to 2 columns

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say "I fixed the height to force the content to go to 2 columns but then it never goes to one column". What you really need to do?

Comment: Do you need dynamics columns? Stay 2 columns when has space and when you resize the browser or mobile devices back to one column?

Comment: Well written answer!

Comment: I don't  need a fixed high I just set it to have two columns. Is there a way to force flex to use all the width with a maximum number of columns ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#in1 {
  background: #a1d;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#in2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#in2>div {
  background: #e25;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/*
#in2 div:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="in1">div1</div>
  <div id="in2">
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I found a near solution:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j2brc3t3/4/)
It answer my question but show a new issue with margins, I need no margin around the container, just 5px between the inner divs, if someone has the perfect solution...